# Understanding regular expression output

Tags: java, regex

I need help to understand the output of the code below. I am unable to figure out the output for `System.out.print(m.start() + m.group());`. Please can someone explain it to me?

```
import java.util.regex.*;
class Regex2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("ab34ef");
        boolean b = false;
        while(b = m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.start()  + m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
0
1
234
4
5
6
```

Note that if I put `System.out.println(m.start() );`, output is:

```
0
1
2
4
5
6
```

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Oh sorry ,Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("ab34ef");

Comment: @azeemj. Edit your question with this infos.

Comment: Your output might be easier to read if you do: `System.out.println(m.start() + " (" + m.group() + ")");`.

Answer (score 5):

Because you have included a `*` character, your pattern will match empty strings as well. When I change your code [as I suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900142/understanding-regular-expression-output#comment31370750_20900142), I get the following output:

```
0 ()
1 ()
2 (34)
4 ()
5 ()
6 ()
```

So you have a large number of empty matches (matching each location in the string) with the exception of `34`, which matches the string of digits. Use `\\d+` if you want to match digits without also matching empty strings..

Comment: Hi, i have 6 strings with the length of 5 .But it prints even 6 also .And How i can identify the empty string.I couldn't understand what u mean by empty String.pls..

Comment: @azeemj. An empty string is `""`. I'm not exactly sure why the match includes index 6, perhaps someone else can elaborate on that.

Answer (score 2):

You used this regex - `\d*` - which basically means **zero or more digits**. Mind the **zero**!

So this pattern will match any group of digits, e.g. `34` **plus** any other position in the string, where the matched sequence will be the empty string.

So, you will have 6 matches, starting at indices 0,1,2,4,5,6. For match starting at index 2, the matched sequence is `34`, while for the remaining ones, the match will be the empty string.

If you want to find only digits, you might want to use this pattern: `\d+`

Answer (score 1):

d* - match zero or more digits in the expresion.

expresion **ab34ef** and his corresponding indices **012345**

On the zero index there is no match so **start()** prints 0 and **group()** prints nothing, then on the first index 1 and nothing, on the second we find match so it prints 2 and 34. Next it will print 4 and nothing and so on.

Another example:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d\\d");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("123ddc2ab23");
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("start:" + matcher.start() + " end:" + matcher.end() + " group:" + matcher.group() + ";");
}
```

which will println:

```
start:0 end:2 group:12;
start:9 end:11 group:23;
```

You will find more information in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html)